# Is there a limit to the number of cells called on in a source range?

Tags: vba

I pieced together a visual basic code that pulls data from cells in multiple workbooks and creates a master summary workbook.  I want to include a large number of cells from each workbook, but the Sub stops working if I include too many cells in the source range.  The first section of code below works fine.  If I add more cells (second section of code), the Sub still runs, but generates a blank workbook.  The rest of the code is identical in both cases.  Is there a maximum number of cells/ characters that I can include in a command?  Even so, I would think this wouldn't exceed such a limit.

THIS CODE WORKS FINE

```
 With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("J2, C2, D7, F7, K7, G10, J10, G11, J11, G12, J12," _
                & "G14, J14, G15, J15, G16, J16, G17, J17, J21," _
                & "J2, D24:E24, G24, I24, J24, O24:S24," _
                & "D25:E25, G25, I25, J25, O25:S25," _
                & "D30:E30, G30, I30, J30, O30:S30")

            End With
```

THIS CODE RETURNS A BLANK WORKSHEET

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set sourceRange = .Range("J2, C2, D7, F7, K7, G10, J10, G11, J11, G12, J12," _
                & "G14, J14, G15, J15, G16, J16, G17, J17, J21," _
                & "J2, D24:E24, G24, I24, J24, O24:S24," _
                & "D25:E25, G25, I25, J25, O25:S25," _
                & "D26:E26, G26, I26, J26, O26:S26," _
                & "D27:E27, G27, I27, J27, O27:S27," _
                & "D28:E28, G28, I28, J28, O28:S28," _
                & "D29:E29, G29, I29, J29, O29:S29," _
                & "D30:E30, G30, I30, J30, O30:S30")

            End With
```

I've tried using different cells and have the same problem; it seems to be the number of cells I choose, not what is in the cells in the original workbook, that is the problem.

Comment: It's not the number of cells that you choose that is the issue, it is the **255 character limit** on a range name.

Comment: I get a 1004 error with your second example...

Comment: you have a possible typo ... J2 is shown twice in both examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `"A1, B1, C1"` syntax is just shorthand for `Range.Union` - use explicit `Range.Union` calls and the sky is the limit!

Answer (score 1):

not meant as an answer  ... just a tip

simplify your range name

```
With mybook.Worksheets(1)
    Set SourceRange = .Range("C2, J2," _
                           & "D7, F7, K7," _
                           & "G10:G12, J10:J12," _
                           & "G14:G17, J14:J17," _
                           & "J21," _
                           & "D24:E30, G24:G30, I24:J30, O24:S30")
End With
SourceRange.Select
Stop                 ' look at your worksheet here to see if the range is correct  ... comment out two lines after verification
```

if you are going to refer to `mybook.worksheets(1)` any place else, then define an object variable and use it, like so

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = mybook.Worksheets(1)

Set SourceRange = ws1.Range("C2, J2," _
                          & "D7, F7, K7," _
                          & "G10:G12, J10:J12," _
                          & "G14:G17, J14:J17," _
                          & "J21," _
                          & "D24:E30, G24:G30, I24:J30, O24:S30")
SourceRange.Select
Stop                 ' look at your worksheet here to see if the range is correct  ... comment out two lines after verification
```